# Почему Web API выводит значения, равные null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, fiddler

Я тестирую этот метод:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    Orders orders = new Orders();
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, orders);
    //try /*(orders.DateOrder > DateTime.Now || orders.DateOrder == null)*/
    //{
    if (orders.DateOrder > DateTime.Now || orders.DateOrder == null)
    {
        result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Orders.ToList()));
       result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }
    return result;
}
```

но почему-то получаю не те значения, которые есть в таблице, а null (или 0), как на картинке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем дело? Может, это потому что я использую Web API внутри MVC проекта? Первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь. Спасибо, надеюсь на помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что выводит вот это `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Orders.ToList())`?

Comment: @tym32167 вот что выдает эта строка https://ru.files.fm/thumb_show.php?i=pekudxy4&view

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, я не могу ходить по таким ссылкам

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: Вот это `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Orders.ToList());` должно вернуть строку, у вас на скрине что то другое.